# Navbar Turn White Background When Scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website for homework and the navbar is giving me a headache.

Here's the website:
http://cdcomunicacao.easr.pt/alunos/al8324/Proposta_1_%20Website/

I want to turn the navbar white when I scroll down the page.

Comment: Post your code and what you have tried so far. és tuga?

Comment: check this -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using onscroll event and scrollTop method can solve problem.

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop > 0 ){
    document.querySelector('header').style.cssText = 'background:white';
    }
    else{
    document.querySelector('header').style.cssText = 'background:transparent';
    }};
```

Comment: I already have a scrip for a scroll up button, and putting that the button disappears, how can i fix that ?

Comment: Comine them in one function;
https://notepad.pw/raw/234aqp426